# Why is logcheck reporting successful Horde logins?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, regular-expression, syslog

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server and use logcheck to report log messages.
I have the `logcheck-database` installed which contains a horde3 ignore file for the server:

```
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ .+\[[0-9]+\]: \[horde\] Login success for [@._[:alnum:]-]+ \[[.0-9]{7,15}\] to Horde \[on line [0-9]+ of ".+"\]$
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ .+\[[0-9]+\]: \[horde\] User [@._[:alnum:]-]+ \[[.0-9]{7,15}\] logged out of Horde \[on line [0-9]+ of ".+"\]$
```

So why is log check reporting the following horde log messages:

```
Feb 20 09:37:13 xxx HORDE: [imp] Login success for xxx@xxx.de (xx.xxx.xxx.xx) to {imap://mail.xxx.de/} [pid 428 on line 157 of "/var/www/horde/imp/lib/Auth.php"]
Feb 20 09:37:37 xxx HORDE: [horde] User xxx@xxx.de logged out of Horde (xx.xx.xxx.xxx) [pid 21839 on line 107 of "/var/www/horde/login.php"]
```

I'm using Horde Webmail 5.2.5.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that the Horde messages have changed a bit so the regular expressions in the horde3 file don't match.

Here are the correct regular expressions for Horde Webmail 5.2.5:

```
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ HORDE: \[imp\] Login success for [@._[:alnum:]-]+ \([.0-9]{7,15}\) to \{[:\/.[:alnum:]-]+\} \[pid [0-9$
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ HORDE: message repeated [0-9]+ times: \[ \[imp\] Login success for [@._[:alnum:]-]+ \([.0-9]{7,15}\) t$
^\w{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ HORDE: \[horde\] User [@._[:alnum:]-]+ logged out of Horde \([.0-9]{7,15}\) \[pid [0-9]+ on line [0-9]$
```

Comment: I've added the regex for the "message repeated x times" log message.